# Replace word using java regex but not quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I want to replace a word in a sentence using java regex replace.

test string is `a_b a__b a_bced adbe  a_bc_d 'abcd' ''abcd''`

if i want to replace all the words which starts with a & ends with d.
i'm using `String.replaceAll("(?i)\\ba[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*d\\b","temp")`.

its replacing as `a_b a__b temp adbe  a_bc_d 'temp' ''temp''`

What should be my regex if i don't want to consider the string in quotes.?

I used `String.replaceAll("[^'](?i)\\ba[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*d\\b[^']","temp")`
Its replacing as `a_b a__btempadbe temp'abcd' ''abcd''`.
Its removing one spaces of that word.
Is there any way to replace only that string not inside the quotes?

PS: there is a workaround for this `String.replaceAll("[^'](?i)\\ba[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*d\\b[^']"," temp ")`. But it fails in some cases.

What should be my regex if i want to replace a word in a sentence & i should not consider string in side quotes.?
Thanks in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookaround assertions:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(?i)(?<!')\\ba[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*d\\b(?!')", "temp");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM6wB8/1)

[Read more about lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Testing if there's or not a quote before and after the target is a wrong approach because you can't know if the described quote is an opening quote or a closing quote. *(try to add a quote at the start of your test string and test a naive pattern, you will see: `'inside'a_outside_d'inside'`)*.

The only way to know if something is inside or outside quotes is to check the string from the beginning *(or from the end, but it's less handy and eventually error prone if quotes aren't balanced)*. To do that, you must describe all possible substrings before the target, example:

```
\G([^a']*+(?:'[^']*'[^a']*|\Ba+[^a']*|a(?!\w*d\b)[^a']*)*+)\ba\w*d\b
```

details:

```
\G  # matches the start of the string or the position after the previous match
(
    [^a']*+ # all that isn't an "a" or a quote
    (?:
        '[^']*'     [^a']* # content between quotes
      |
        \Ba+        [^a']* # "a" not at the start of a word
      |
        a(?!\w*d\b) [^a']* # "a" at the start of a word that doesn't end with "d"
    )*+
) # all that can be before the target in a capture group
\ba\w*d\b # the target
```

Don't forget to escape backslashes in the java string: `\` => `\\`.

To perform the replacement, you need to refer to the capture group 1:

```
$1temp
```

Note: to handle escaped quotes between quotes, change `'[^']*'` to:
 `'[^\\']*+(?s:\\.[^\\']*)*+'`.

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/61ajwa): click the Java button.